# MySQL JOIN get the value of a column based on another column in the same table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

Table tagente

```
|id_agente | nombre | id_grupo |
|------------------------------|
| 3        |  mark  |    4     |
```

Table tagent_secondary_group

```
|id     | id_agente | id_group |
|------------------------------|
|  2    |    3      |    8     |
```

Table tgrupo

```
|id_grupo |   nombre   | parent|
|------------------------------|
|  8      | servers    |  10   |
|  10     | datacenter |  0    |
```

The "parent" column in the "tgrupo" table reference the "id_grupo"  of the same table,
So the parent of servers is datacenter.

And I need to get the "nombre" value based on the parent value.

How can I do this? It can be done on the same query?

```
SELECT  ta.nombre as agente ,tg.nombre as grupo , tg.parent 
FROM tagente ta
JOIN tagent_secondary_group tsg ON ta.id_agente  = tsg.id_agent 
JOIN tgrupo tg ON tsg.id_group = tg.id_grupo
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you just include the table twice with two different aliases.  I write it here with `WHERE`, but it can be redone with `JOIN`s.

```
SELECT  ta.nombre as agente , tg2.nombre as grupo , tg1.parent 
FROM tagente ta, tagent_secondary_group tsg, tgrupo tg1, tgrupo tg2
WHERE ta.id_agente = tsg.id_agent
  AND tsg.id_group = tg1.id_grupo
  AND tg1.parent = tg2.id_grupo;
```

Comment: comma seeperated joins are since more than 10 years ourdated

Comment: Since 30 years now... (SQL-92)

Comment: Comma means cross join with higher precedence than keyword JOINs, and the arguments against is are specious.